# Ubuntu EFI boot entry created on its own, even if just booting Live-USB

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

On my Windows 10 laptop, (UEFI Secure boot), I can boot from Ubuntu18:04 live-USB, successfully. I don't actually install Ubuntu ( I choose "Try Ubuntu"). Still, when I reboot (after proper Shutdown and removing USB), I get Windows boot menu with Win-10 and Ubuntu as option. It means, this EFI entry is being created on its own, even if it is just a live-cd session.

Each time, I have to manually remove the EFI boot entry.
How can I avoid this situation ? Please help.